# How to merge two branches with different directory hierarchies in git?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I started using Maven with a web application project so the directory hierarchy changed. I created a new branch for the Maven integration. Now I have two branches one with the old directory hierarchy and one with the maven directory hierarchy. Both branches have new commits (bugfixes and new features).

I would like to get rid of the old branch and merge its changes to the Maven branch. Git merge gives countless conflicts that feels like impossible to resolve. I believe that this is because file paths have changed.

What is the best way to approach this merge?

Comment: Just so other readers know: the typical error message for these problems is `too many files skipping inexact rename detection`.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Try setting `merge.renameLimit` to something high for this merge. git tries to detect renames, but only if the number of files is below this limit, since it requires O(n^2) processing time:

```
git config merge.renameLimit 999999
```

then when done:

```
git config --unset merge.renameLimit
```

Comment: Note after increasing renameLimit, I had to run "git merge --abort" so I could retry the pull. Otherwise, this did the trick.

Answer (score 28):

The blog post "[Confluence, git, rename, merge oh my…](http://web.archive.org/web/20181116112221/https://www.atlassian.com/blog/archives/confluence_git_rename_merge_oh_my) " adds some interesting information which illustrates [Robie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478206/robie-basak)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4722641/6309) (upvoted):

> When trying to detect renames git distinguishes between **exact and inexact renames** with:
>
> - the former being a rename without changing the content of the file and
> - the latter a rename that might include changes to the content of the file (e.g. renaming/moving a Java Class).
>
> This distinction is important because the algorithm for detecting exact renames is linear and will always be executed while the algorithm for inexact rename detection is quadratic ( `O(n^2)` ) and git does not attempt to do this if the number of files changed exceeds a certain threshold (1000 by default).
>
> When not explicitly set, `merge.renameLimit` defaults to 1000 files or uses the value for `diff.renameLimit` if set.
> The `diff.renameLimit` affects `git diff`, `git show` and `git log` while `merge.renameLimit` applies to merge attempts (`git merge`, `git cherry-pick`) only.
>
> It’s a good idea to change the `merge.renameLimit` as opposed to changing the `diff.renameLimit` so that git does not attempt to find renames during common operations like looking at the `git diff` output.
>
> To show renames, commands like `git show` or `git log` can be used with the `-M` option that turns rename detection on.

[Linus mentions](http://web.archive.org/web/20170306112143/http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Merging-limitations-after-directory-renames-interesting-test-repo-td6041103.html#a6041833):

> Yeah, for the kernel, I have
>
> ```
>    [diff]
>            renamelimit=0
> ```
>
> to disable the limit entirely, because the default limit is very low indeed. Git is quite good at the rename detection.
>
> However, the reason for the low default is not because it's not snappy enough - it's because it can end up using a lot of memory (and if you're low on memory, the swapping will mean that it goes from "quite snappy" to "slow as molasses" - but it still will not be CPU limited, it's just paging like crazy).