# git merge ignores deleted files, existing on merged branch (renamed files)

Tags: git, merge

I've got the branches `feature1` and `master`.
Then in `feature1` I renamed a file `dir/file.txt` into `dir2/file2.txt`.
After that I altered the file in `master` and a week later altered the file in `feature1` too.

I have 40 files changed like that across the project.
When I try to merge **`master` into `feature1`** I'm using low renaming threshold.
Most of the files are auto-merged correctly. Some files are offered for manual conflict resolution.

But some concrete files **neither appear in the `merge` response as auto-merged,

nor getting merged properly**. Under *properly* I expect one of two outcomes I could resolve:
1. It wouldnt detect renaming and just add me another `dir/file.txt` into the `feature1` branch.
2. It would detect renaming and offer me to manually resolve conflict.

There are many changes when I view them with
`git difftool master:dir/file.txt feature1:dir2/file2.txt`

Therefore I assume that git recognizes the renaming and decides to keep my version
without informing me about what's going on.
How can I solve it / debug it ?

**This is the command I use**

```
git config merge.renameLimit 9999999999
git merge --no-ff -Xrename-threshold=20 -Xignore-space-change master
```

## Upd1

While working with `feature1` branch, I had deleted `dir/file.txt`.
Maybe git assumes this file should be deleted and therefore ignores it's existence in `master`.
Renaming detection fails, although the similarity of the files is kept ( levenshtein distance is less than 2% of the content's length )
[Another discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407638/git-merge-removing-files-i-want-to-keep) suggests 'manual merge' copying files from branch to branch.

## Upd2

Some other files are resolved correctly
`CONFLICT (rename/delete): images/ab.gif deleted in master and renamed in HEAD. Version HEAD of cdn/img/ab.gif left in tree.`
Files that were removed in `master` and merged into `feature1` are resolved correctly. Files that are deleted (or moved) in `feature1`  ain't recognized at the merge.
**Sugestions?**

## Upd3

At the moment I'm trying to merge the other way around. Merge `feature1` into `master` and see what files 
are being added and removed. This way I'll a list of files git fail's to recognize as renames and resort to manual merging.

Comment: have you tried rebasing feature1 on top of master, instead of merging master into feature1?

Comment: I did. Got the same effect but with different files being 'forgotten'.  I ended up manually merging those few files that were deleted and renamed.

Comment: That's interesting; this seems like exactly the type of situation rebase would handle well. You might try messing with merge strategies, but I'm not sure about the root of your issue. http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html (Merge strategies section)

Comment: Perhaps the resolution here will help:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722423/how-to-merge-two-branches-with-different-directory-hierarchies-in-git

Comment: How are you deleting the files under version control?  git rm will help manage these things and do the right thing.  If it is a move, then git mv will do the right thing.

Of course, you still need to stage them.

Concerning your third update, don't forget that you are allowed to checkout files directly from other branches or repositories.  This may assist in your recovering those files.

Comment: Do all the files have a common ancestry?  I also would like to know if you are using git rm and git mv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are deleting files from your repo - git is tracking this deletion and the merge is considering this when determining what to do.

This is probably not all that you have going on, but it is part of it.  You can try git add'ing them again.

Comment: That turned out to be the problem. As noted in upd1, I had some files deleted in my `feature1` branch and whet `master` was merged in, git recognized it was the same file and thus skipped it ( as it thought this file should not appear in the `feature1` branch at all.

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore I assume that git recognizes the renaming and decides to keep my version without informing me about what's going on.

Git 2.13 (Q2 2017) will actually tell you more about what is going on:

> When "`git merge`" detects a path that is renamed in one history while the other history deleted (or modified) it, **it now reports both paths to help the user understand what is going on in the two histories being merged**.

See [commit b26d87f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b26d87f2da22a5970b15bebe588bcd6ccac98e9b) (28 Jan 2017) by [Matt McCutchen (`mattmccutchen`)](https://github.com/mattmccutchen).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 74aabf4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/74aabf41cee31f7937f9445a99597403da50585b), 27 Feb 2017)</sup>

> ### merge-recursive: make "CONFLICT (rename/delete)" message show both paths
>
> The current message printed by "`git merge-recursive`" for a rename/delete
>   conflict is like this:

```
CONFLICT (rename/delete): 
new-path deleted in HEAD and renamed in other-branch. 
Version other-branch of new-path left in tree.
```

> To be more helpful, the message should show both paths of the rename and
>   state that the deletion occurred at the old path, not the new path.  So
>   change the message to the following format:

```
CONFLICT (rename/delete): 
old-path deleted in HEAD and renamed to  new-path in other-branch.  
Version other-branch of new-path left in tree.
```

> Since this doubles the number of cases in handle_change_delete (modify vs.
>   rename), refactor the code to halve the number of cases again by merging the
>   cases where o->branch1 has the change and o->branch2 has the delete with the
>   cases that are the other way around.